# Java EE if/else statement not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have this function here that assembles an API call to eBay. It used to only work with one EbayKeys.appid now there arose a need to include a second one.

The parameter String appidGet is passed from another function that uses request.getParameter("token"); I've output the value into catalina.out and the value gets passed, however the if/else statement does not get executed and it does not append the values onto the string.

I have tried it with several different values and none of them work. I'm completely new to Java and have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

```
public String getSearchUrl(String qurl, List<String> excludes, String appidGet) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String query = buildQuery(qurl, excludes);
    String safequery;
    try {
        safequery = URLEncoder.encode(getQuery(),charset);
        StringBuffer apicall = new StringBuffer();
        apicall.append(EbayKeys.endpoint).append("?").append("OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords")
        .append("&SERVICE-VERSION=").append(EbayKeys.version);

        //Does not execute
        if (appidGet == "one" ) {
            apicall.append("&SECURITY-APPNAME=").append(EbayKeys.appid1);
        }           
        else if (appidGet == "two" ) {
            apicall.append("&SECURITY-APPNAME=").append(EbayKeys.appid2);
        }

        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " "
                + Utils.getTime()
                + " APP ID = " + appidGet);
        apicall.append("&GLOBAL-ID=").append(EbayKeys.globalid)
        .append("&keywords=").append(safequery)
        .append("&sortOrder=StartTimeNewest&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=2")
        .append(query);
        return apicall.toString();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classic mistake. When comparing Strings, use `.equals()`:

```
    if (appidGet.equals("one") ) {
        apicall.append("&SECURITY-APPNAME=").append(EbayKeys.appid1);
    }           
    else if (appidGet.equals("two") ) {
        apicall.append("&SECURITY-APPNAME=").append(EbayKeys.appid2);
    }
```

For non-primitives, `==` tests if the two objects are *the same* object (same memory address), whereas `.equals()` tests if they "seem the same" (class-specific implementation)

Answer (score 5):

You should use

```
appidGet.equals("one")
```

and

```
appidGet.equals("two")
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare strings with `.equals()`

`==` In Java compares by object reference since strings are objects in Java.

Try `appidGet.equals("one")`

Answer (score 1):

Classic java mistake.

In java, "==" compares the reference of objects, so, use equals instead of ==.